# EBS Volume attributes

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-ec2

This may be a stupid question, but I've got stucked trying to get EBS volume attributes in .NET. As far as I understood, I can't get all of the volume attributes at once (which would be the best), I have to specify which attribute I want to describe, like this:

```
var dvar = new DescribeVolumeAttributeRequest
{
   Attribute = "some attribute name",
   VolumeId = volumeID
};
```

but where can I get the names of these attributes? I searched back and forth, but couldn't find any list of names for thev. I thought maybe there's some enum or something, but couldn't find it either.

Comment: I'm not from a .net background but as per my understanding once the connection with aws is established. You can pull the info related to all the volumes or anything else at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can access volume information using DescribeVolumesRequest like this:

```
AmazonEC2 ec2 = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonEC2Client(AWSAccessKey, AWSSecretKey);
var request = new DescribeVolumesRequest()
                    .WithVolumeId(volume);
var response = ec2.DescribeVolumes(request);
Volume v = response.DescribeVolumesResult.Volume[0];
```

Where 'volume' is the volume-id you want to get the attributes of.